# Different setter and getter types in Haskell's lenses

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I've got a `data type` `G`, which have got field `_repr :: Data.Graph.Inductive.Gr String String`. The normal way, when adding new node into `Gr` graph, we have to provide an `LNode a` object, which basically is defined as a tuple of `(Int, a)`, where Int is the nodes index in Graph - see the example function `add` below.

I want to implement a function `addx`, which will compute the index automatically (for example by using `Data.Graph.Inductive.newNodes` function). I want the `addx` to have signature of `addx :: String -> G -> Int` and this function will compute new free index, modify the graph G and return this computed index. Is it possible in Haskell to create such function (which will modify an existing object - `G` in this case) - by using lenses or something like that?

I have seen, that Haskell lens is defined like `lens :: (a -> c) -> (a -> d -> b) -> Lens a b c d` and lens is basically a "getter" and "setter", so its signature allows for different types of getter output (`c`), setter value (`d`) and setter output (`b`).

```
import qualified Data.Graph.Inductive     as DG

data G = G { _repr :: DG.Gr String String, _name::String} deriving ( Show )

empty :: G
empty = G DG.empty ""

add :: DG.LNode String -> G -> G
add node g = g{_repr = DG.insNode node $ _repr g}

-- is it possible to define it?
addx :: String -> G -> Int
addx name g = undefined

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let g = add (1, "test2")
          $ add (0, "test1")
          $ empty

        n1 = addx "test2" g
        g2 = DG.insEdge(n1,0)
           $ DG.insEdge(0,1)

    print $ g
```

Answer (score 2):

Your type for `addx` is broken since you can't modify `G` in a pure function without returning the modified form like `addx1 :: String -> G -> (Int, G)`. If you have a clever eye for Haskell monads, you might notice that this has an isomorphic type, `addx2 :: String -> State G Int`.

We can align everything to this "stateful" orientation

```
add' node = do g <- get
               put $ g { _repr = DB.insNode node $ _repr g }
```

and make it more succinct with lenses

```
add'' node = repr %= DB.insNode node
```

---

The real challenge here is, at the end of the day, tracking the node identity. One way would be to carry it alongside the `repr` in your type

```
data G = G { _repr :: DG.Gr String String, _name :: String, _index :: Int } 
empty = G DG.empty "" 0
```

then use that when building nodes (using lenses again!)

```
addx' name = do i <- use index
                repr %= DB.insNode (i, node)
                i += 1
```